# How to solve BeanCreationException ploblem while upgrading grails version from 2.4.5 to 2.5.0?

Tags: grails-2.5

I'm upgrading grails version to 2.5.0 from 2.4.5. The problem that occurred while running my project is -

> Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'com.athena.mis.application.model.ListSupplierActionServiceModelValidator': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator.setProxyHandler(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.proxy.ProxyHandler); nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.access$100(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.athena.mis.application.model.**ListSupplierActionServiceModel**Validator': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator.setProxyHandler(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.proxy.ProxyHandler); nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.access$100(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;

`ListSupplierActionServiceModel` is a groovy class in my project and it's cache usage is read-only.

Answer (score 5):

I had quite a hard time fixing this one...

Simply remove the `.slcache` directory in your grails project root folder and you're done !

Answer (score 0):

Differently from what Ludovic reported, I actually found that I had to delete the `.slcache` directory from `$HOME/.grails/`